# Replicate Excel's IF and COUNTIF functions in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to replicate the ability of Excel countif and if statements in Pandas.

In Excel, I have the following table:

```
+---------+-------+------+--------+
| Row/Col |   A   |  B   |   C    |
+---------+-------+------+--------+
|       1 | Name  | Date | Type   |
|       2 | John  | 21/4 | New    |
|       3 | John  | 22/4 | Update |
|       4 | Jacob | 23/6 | New    |
|       5 | Mary  | 24/7 | New    |
|       6 | Jacob | 26/8 | Update |
+---------+-------+------+--------+
```

In order to get the Type values, I would use the following code in all of column C (for row 2):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A2:A2, A2)>1, "Update", "New")
```

For the same data in a df, how would I implement it, so that I counts only from the first row of the column down, and does not include any row below the row it is calculating for?

Comment: I don't know (or care) about excel, can you instead please show us your expected result?

Comment: The expected outcome is column C

Answer (score 1):

In panda we have `groupby` with `cumcount`

```
df['C']=df.groupby('A').cumcount().gt(0).map({False:'New',True:'Update'})
```